# django-celery infrastructure over multiple servers, broker is redis

Tags: python, django, architecture, celery

Currently we have everything setup on single cloud server, that includes:

- Database server
- Apache
- Celery
- redis to serve as a broker for celery and for some other tasks
- etc

Now we are thinking to break apart the main components to separate servers e.g. separate database server, separate storage for media files, web servers behind load balancers. The reason is to not to pay for one heavy server and use load balancers to create servers on demand to reduce cost and improve overall speed.

I am really confused about celery only, have anyone ever used celery on multiple production servers behind load balancers? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Consider one small use case which is currently how it is been done on single server (confusion is that how that can be done when we use multiple servers):

- User uploads a `abc.pptx` file->reference is stored in database->stored on server disk
- A task (convert document to pdf) is created and goes in redis (broker) queue
- celery which is running on same server picks the task from queue

  - Read the file, convert it to pdf using software called `docsplit`
  - create a folder on server disk (which will be used as static content later on) puts pdf file and its thumbnail and plain text and the original file

Considering the above use case, how can you setup up multiple web servers which can perform the same functionality?

Comment: you want celeryd processes splited on multiple servers?

Comment: you can simply launch multiple celeryd,, (at least rabbitmq broker is pub subing as anycast)

Answer (score 5):

Celery actually makes this pretty simple, since you're already putting the tasks on a queue. All that changes with more workers is that each worker takes whatever's next on the queue - so multiple workers can process at once, each on their own machine.

There's three parts to this, and you've already got one of them.

1. Shared storage, so that all machines can access the same files
2. A broker that can hand out tasks to multiple workers - redis is fine for that
3. Workers on multiple machines

Here's how you set it up:

- User uploads file to front-end server, which stores in your shared storage (e.g. S3, Samba, NFS, whatever), and stores the reference in the database
- Front-end server kicks off a celery task to process the file e.g.

`def my_view(request):
    # ... deal with storing the file
    file_in_db = store_file(request)
    my_process_file_task.delay(file_in_db.id)  # Use PK of DB record
    # do rest of view logic...`

- On each processing machine, run celery-worker:
  `python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=INFO -Q default -E`

Then as you add more machines, you'll have more workers and the work will be split between them.

Key things to ensure:

- You must have shared storage, or this gets much more complicated
- Every worker machine must have the right Django/Celery settings to be able to find the redis broker and the shared storage (e.g. S3 bucket, keys etc)

Comment: What should I do to make each worker read the tasks from the queue? I spent many hours to find a good example, not nothing found. Thanks

Comment: So this `...(file_in_db.id)  # Use PK of DB record` implicates that the celery machine must also be able to access the same database as the front-end server. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, there has to be *some* shared knowledge between the front-end and backend servers. That doesn't have to be a PK - it could be a GUID to track the task, a filepath or something else. But *somehow* the front and back ends need to know what they are talking about

Answer (score 4):

What will strongly simplify your processing is some shared storage, accessible from all cooperating servers. With such design, you may distribute the work among more servers without worrying on which server will be next processing step done.

## Using AWS S3 (or similar) cloud storage

If you can use some cloud storage, like AWS S3, use that.

In case you have your servers running at AWS too, you do not pay for traffic within the same region, and transfers are quite fast.

Main advantage is, your data are available from all the servers under the same bucket/key name, so you do not have to bother about who is processing which file, as all have shared storage on S3.

note: If you need to get rid of old files, you may even set up some policy file on give bucket, e.g. to delete files older than 1 day or 1 week.

## Using other types of shared storage

There are more options

- Samba
- central file server
- FTP
- Google storage (very similar to AWS S3)
- Swift (from OpenStack)
- etc.

For small files you could even use Redis, but such solutions are for good reasons rather rare.