# Celery：how to seprate worker and client into different servers

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I was using Django as webserver, and redis as broker

when Django received a request, it starts an asynic task,this task may cost 10 hours, so i used Celery.

My goal is :one server,call it server 1, runs the Django(webapp,send task into redis),another server,call it server2, runs the worker,which actually excute the task.

Someone says just copy all the project on server 2,and start an worker.But the web part is uncessary. I want only the task part on server 2.

this is my Django proj

```
proj                                                                  
|
---proj
|    |
|    ---celery.py
|
---app
    |
    tasks.py
```

BTW：can you tell me how to generate the document architecture,what a pity

In the tasks.py ,there is a function called do_train()

the view.py

```
class Testcelery(APIView):
def get(self, request, para, format=None):
    r = do_train.delay()
    print(r.id)
    # result = add.delay(4, 4)
    # print(result.id)
    result = OrderedDict()
    result['result'] = r.id
    result['code'] = status.HTTP_200_OK
    result['message'] = 'success'
    return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

so send a task in the redis.

I start a worker on server 2,but it always says

```
KeyError: 'app.tasks.do_train'
```

the pure celery project on server 2

```
proj                                                                  
|
---celery.py
|
---app
    |
    tasks.py
```

Comment: In your celery.py do you have `app = Celery(`? In there you can specify `include=['app.tasks.do_train']`; Also from experience I think your tasks must have the same path on both client and server, so if your server awaits a task `app.tasks.do_train` then your client should call this task like this `app.tasks.do_train.delay(your,parameters,here)` (but I am not 100% sure on this so take it with pinch of salt)

Answer (score -1):

I believe that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551808/django-celery-infrastructure-over-multiple-servers-broker-is-redis) provides a really good, in depth explanation of how you would do it. I would suggest you just biting the bullet and having the source code on both machines, and you just need to properly configure the Redis settings in your settings.py file. I am uncertain, though, what you mean when you are asking for help generating the document architecture.