# Trying to Run Celery Tasks on Remote Server

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

I have been scouring the Internet for some sort of guide for setting up django, celery, and redis so the celery task runs on a remote server, and I cannot seem to find out how to do this.

I have three machines - tsunami (development), trout (production), and t-rex (Nvidia card). I am running some image manipulation algorithms using celery and redis. I have the same django/celery code base on all three computers. When I run the algorithms on tsunami or trout without CUDA support, it takes hours to complete. When I run the same algorithms on t-rex with CUDA support, they complete in minutes. What I would like to do is offload the celery tasks from trout and tsunami to t-rex, and return the results to the either trout or tsunami. By results, I mean a file to save on the local file system or data added to the local mysql (8.0.32) database. Is this even possible?

Can someone point me to a guide on how to set this up? I am running django 4.1.7, celery 5.2.7 and redis server 6.0.16. Trout and tsunami are running Ubuntu 20.04, and t-rex is Ubuntu 22.04. All are running Python 3.8.

I am concerned that when I install dlib on trout and tsunami, it is compiled without CUDA support because there are no Nvidia cards. All machines are running dlib 19.24.0, but only t-rex has it compiled with CUDA support. Is this a show stopper for my plan to use t-rex as a remote CUDA processor for the other machines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need setup different task queues and routes for your servers.

Check out the celery docs on [how to setup task routing](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing)

To specify routes define `task_routes`. Let's say you have your task that runs image manipulation defined under the module `feed.tasks`, use something like the following in your celery configuration to ensure that those tasks are only sent to the feeds queue:

```py
app.conf.task_routes = {'feed.tasks.*': {'queue': 'feeds'}}
```

To specify what queues to consume from, modify your celery worker script and give a comma separated list of queues using the -Q option:

```bash
$ celery -A proj worker -l INFO -Q foo,bar,baz,feeds
```

By default celery worker will read from all queues. You can exclude queues on tsunami and trout, using the `-X` option

```bash
$ celery -A proj worker -l INFO -X feeds
```

Comment: Thanks! After reading this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551808/django-celery-infrastructure-over-multiple-servers-broker-is-redis, it seems I have to have (1) a shared file system for the celery workers to read/write data and (2) a shared database for the celery workers to read and write. Is that true?

Comment: After looking at the task routing page, I don't see how to route tasks to different redis servers. If tsunami has to process an image, don't I have to send that task to the redis server on t-rex so a celery task there can do the processing?

Comment: You will need some way to transmit the results back to trout or tsunami, ex shared file system, shared database, etc. would work. In order to get your task queues shared across servers, you need to point your `CELERY_BROKER_URL` on all of your servers to the same redis server.

Answer (score 0):

Here servers can be docker images (docker-compose) or containers or pods (on k8s). 
*Common tasks on all servers*

1. copy the project
2. pip install -r requirements.txt

server A: run django server as `python manage.py runserver` (if using uvicorn or gunicorn, then run the appropriate app server accordingly).

server B: `celery -A proj_name worker`

server C: `celery -A proj_name worker -l INFO -Q foo,bar` # logging level is Info and run tasks on queue foo and bar.

server D: `celery -A proj_name worker -l INFO -Q email,url` # logging level is Info and runs tasks on queue email and url.

Btw the location to start the django server and celery worker is the same, that is the project's root directory, that is the directory where the manage.py is located.
If you have multiple remote executors, for the sake of redundancy and high availability or fault tolerance, it is recommended to have a queue run on more than 1 worker. ex:-

server B: `celery -A proj_name worker -l INFO -Q foo,bar` 
server C: `celery -A proj_name worker -l INFO -Q bar,email` 
server D: `celery -A proj_name worker -l INFO -Q email,foo` 
server B,C both process queue bar.
server C,D both process queue email.
server D,B both process queue bar.